# How To merge many tif files to single tif file?

Tags: pdf, merge, tiff, ghostscript

I have so many tif files that I want to convert into a single one. I am on Ubuntu 11.04, how can I do it? and I was tried convert tif to single pdf, but I stuck when convert pdf to tif, I use ghoscript with this command :

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -q -g300x300 -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -dBATCH -sOutputFile=result.tif source.pdf
```

but the result it's not good. :( . any suggestion for my problem?

Thanks before.

Answer (score 12):

use **tiffcp**

```
usage: tiffcp [options] input... output.tiff
```

for instance:

```
tiffcp *.tiff output.tiff
```

and you will have a resulting multipage tiff

then **tiff2pdf** (a wrapper for ghostscript)

```
usage:  tiff2pdf [options] input.tiff
```

Comment: Hello dingo, thats not working for me, tiff file is generated but can't open in picture viewer.. :(

Comment: a multipage tiff needs a multipage viewer, like **qfaxreader**, but if you convert to pdf, resulting file can be more easily seen with pdf viewers

Answer (score 7):

To install *tiffcp* use `apt-get install libtiff-tools`